# Android WebRTC Local AudioTrack is not streaming audio

Tags: android, webrtc, audiotrack

I am developing an android app with Audio call feature by using WebRTC. I have written the code with latest build available for android. When i receive a call from client, i am able to Connect client successfully. Problem is, i can hear client audio but my audio is not streaming to client. Below is the code.

```
factory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setAudioDeviceModule(adm)
            .setOptions(options)
            .createPeerConnectionFactory();
peerConnection = createPeerConnection(factory);
    if(peerConnection != null){
        remoteAudioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
        remoteAudioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack("5555",remoteAudioSource);

        //Local audio track
        List<String> mediaStreamLabels = Collections.singletonList("ARDAMS");
        peerConnection.addTrack(createAudioTrack(),mediaStreamLabels);
        peerConnection.setAudioRecording(true);
        peerConnection.setAudioPlayout(true);
    }

    private AudioTrack createAudioTrack() {
       localAudioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
       localAudioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack(AUDIO_TRACK_ID, localAudioSource);
       localAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);//Enable audio
     return localAudioTrack;
 }
```

Comment: May I see the complete code on how you adding the remoteAudioTrack to PeerConnection? Also, I like to see the entire code to understand it better on what exactly went wrong

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution to your problem? 
I only have issues with one device which does not stream audio track to the other end.